# What is the equivalent of Java's transient in Serde?

Tags: serialization, rust, serde

I am interested in making a variable not automatically serialized (e.g., by Serde) with the use of a keyword like Java's `transient`, but in Rust. I need this to store passwords. Of course, I could manually clear the data upon serialization to the disk, but I would like to know if there are better, more automatic, options.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the `#[serde(skip)]` attribute:

```
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize}; // 1.0.88

#[derive(Deserialize, Serialize)]
struct MyStruct {
    field1: i32, // this will be (de)serialized
    #[serde(skip)]
    field2: i32, // this will be skipped
}
```

If the type needs to be ***de***serialized, it's a good idea to accompany a `#[serde(skip)]` with a `#[serde(default)]` (or a `#[serde(default = "fn_name")]`) attribute. Serde deserializes  skipped fields as if a `#[serde(default)]` was implicitly added, but it's clearer to someone reading your code if you make it explicit where this value will come from.

See:

- [List of all serde field attributes](https://serde.rs/field-attrs.html)
- [All serde attributes](https://serde.rs/attributes.html)